# GAM: set knot locations for first but not second smooth term

Tags: generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm modelling a time series of detection records for two different viruses. My outcome variable is the count of virus detections per month through time.

I have included a cyclic spline for month to capture cyclical patterns in annual virus detection records. For this cyclic spline I have set knot locations as I read [here](https://fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2014/05/09/modelling-seasonal-data-with-gam/) that this can help to reduce bias and error. However, I have also included a second spline to capture long-term trends in virus detection records.

Q: How will the knot locations be set for my second spline `s(Time)`? Will the knot locations for this spline also be dictated by my call `knots = knots` - this is not my intention, nor what I want. If possible, I would like to set the knot locations for `s(nMonth)` but let the `gam()` function set/decide the knot locations for all other smooths/splines that may be included in my model. Is this possible?

```
knots <- list(month = c(0.5, seq(1, 12, length = 10), 12.5))

gam(Number ~ State + Virus + State*Virus + s(nMonth, bs = "cc", k = 12, by = Virus) + s(Time, k = 12, by = Virus), 
            data = supply.pad, 
            family = nb(), 
            method = "REML", 
            knots = knots)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cyclic splines you can just set the end points, which is better than what you did as you don't have equally-spaced knots.

```r
knots <- list(month = c(0.5, 12.5))
```

with that, {mgcv} will spread the required number of knots evenly over the requested interval.

Any covariate that isn't named in `knots` will just have the knots for the basis (if needed) set using the default approach - evenly over the interval. However, because you didn't specify `bs` in the second smooth, you get the default spline which is a low-rank thin plate regression spline. These splines have a knot at each unique data location (unique covariate value), but to make them low-rank, Simon does an eigen decomposition of the full basis retaining only the `k` first eigen vectors to preserve much of the original full basis without actually requiring one basis function per unique value of the covariate. As a result, there aren't knots in you don't specify them for the TPRS basis.